# Cleaned up a mess of a question for user just to have it deleted

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

Is there anything to stop the users from deleting their cleaned up posts?
I completely cleaned up this post
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3916570/show-that-nt1-1re-alpha-ntnt-is-equivalent-to-nt1-1r1

then user just deletes it, can I get back the question posted under me instead?

Comment: If you got the text of the question you could post it as your own question. Before doing so I'd hope you'd give a quick think as to whether the question is worth posting, or if you're mostly just irritated by having your work wasted by someone else (which I would certainly be). I think anyone with 10k+ rep could snag the text for you. And there may be implications to posting work that originated with someone else. My opinion is that they gave up any right, moral or legal, to stop you, having posting and deleted, but that's nothing more than my opinion

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC Well, that's my opinion too.

Comment: I agree with the other comments, but if you re-ask the question, be sure to address the reason(s) why it was closed and deleted in the first place, in your reposting.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The title is

```
Show that $n(t+1)=(1+r)e^{-\alpha n(t)}n(t)$ is equivalent 
to $n(t+1)=(1+r)^{1-\frac{n(t)}{K}} n(t)$ 
where $K=\frac{\ln (1+r)}{\alpha}$
```

and the question body is

```
Show that $n(t+1)=(1+r)e^{-\alpha n(t)}n(t)$ is equivalent to 
$n(t+1)=(1+r)^{1-\frac{n(t)}{K}} n(t)$ where 
$K=\frac{\ln (1+r)}{\alpha}$

I also have to show that $n(t+1)$ will grow when $r<0$ 
and the initial population is greater than $n=k$. 
I have also tried to show this but using both variations 
of the equation I get an increasingly negative value.
```

its only tag is [mathematical-modeling]. As mentioned in comments, if you do plan to repost the question, make sure to improve the question. In addition to adding context, e.g. it might be useful to think of other tags; the problem statement could use a full-stop at the end; it seems that $k=K$; display math mode might look nicer; etc.

PS your edit description “got rid of the sad sub story” could have made it more likely that the post was deleted.